# How to customize android style in FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'd like to customize the FirebaseUI style for the login activity.
I used a bit of [this github](https://gist.github.com/cutiko/9942f76504cbb67c8d04ee6632286dbc).

So far so good but I'd like to take off the shadow below the action bar.

I tried taking off the elevation but still showing up.

```
    <style name="LoginTheme" parent="FirebaseUI">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

Any recommendation is very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

Comment: I don't think answering my own question is valid here because I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39136738/unable-to-hide-the-title-bar-of-authorization-activity-using-firebaseui) 

It pretty much says you need to overlay the styles to kinda trick FirebaseUI, pretty cool